# Overloading the operator () in MPI

Tags: c++, return, overloading, mpi

Hope you are doing well in these times.

I am attempting to write a parallelized solver in C/C++ and have an array distributed over the processes (p).

In an attempt to overload the operator '( )'; in order to return the local value of the distributed array from the respective process, I have a function as follows:

```
**double&** operator()(int r, int c)
{
           int rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
           int size = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();
           int globalIndex = r * mcols() + c;
           if (globalIndex >= lo && globalIndex <= (lo + bloc))
                        **return localData [ globalIndex % lo];**
}
```

The problem comes in the highlighted sections where I would like only one process (the one that has the value) to return it, however all the processes attempt on the returning some value. I end up with an mpi runtime error where the processes have a function without a return value (for when the condition fails).

(1) Is there a way in which I can selectively choose a specific process to execute a function
(2) Or is there a way I can exit a function without returning a value.
(3) this is a semantics problem, is there way that this case is handled

Answer (score 0):

You can return a pointer, not a reference.

```
double* operator()(int r, int c)
{
           int rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
           int size = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();
           int globalIndex = r * mcols() + c;
           if (globalIndex >= lo && globalIndex <= (lo + bloc))
                        return &localData [ globalIndex % lo];
           return nullptr;
}
```